# Multilength array of array based on dataframe values

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

I've got say a 'theoretical' dataset with multiple occurrences of different ids. For example, 191 (three times); 192 (11 times); 193 (4 times) and etc. I just want to convert this dataframe column to an array of arrays of different length using numpy. I know that there is a .reshape() method that returns arrays of fixed length, but this kinda conditional shape formatting is out of the scope of my knowledge.

Comment: Will you please provide an actual sample of your dataframe?

Comment: 'an array of arrays of different length' sounds like a `ragged array`.  If made with `object` dtype, the result is a 1d array, where the elements are arrays (or lists) that vary in size.  As such it's little better than a list of arrays.  Math on such an array is hit-or-miss, and slower than a regular multidimensional array.